# Converting currency needs proper round(2)

Tags: ruby

This is my code to convert local currency to EUR

```
price_eur = price.to_i / 3.4528
price_eur = price_eur.round(2)
```

The problem is, if `price=0.8`, I get result `price_eur=0.0`, why?

How to make it `0.80` (proper value AND always leading zero)?

Comment: Instead of `price.to_i` do `price.to_f`.

Comment: That's a *trailing* zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_i` rounds down to the nearest integer - so `0.8.to_i` is zero. And then zero over anything else remains zero.

You can't use an integer - use a float. `price.to_f`

And then, use `sprintf('%.2f', price_eur)` to print it as a string, with a leading zero.

```
pry 2.1.2 (main):0 > price = 0.8
0.8
=>
pry 2.1.2 (main):0 > price_eur = price.to_f / 3.4528
0.23169601482854496
=>
pry 2.1.2 (main):0 > price_eur = price_eur.round(2)
0.23
=>
pry 2.1.2 (main):0 > sprintf('%.2f', price_eur)
"0.23"
=>
pry 2.1.2 (main):0 >
```

Edit: note comment from @Stefan not to use floats, and to use BigDecimal instead. Really, the easiest way to deal with money is probably to use the Money gem, which already handles a lot of these problems: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

Comment: That does not create such thing as `0.80`. It just prints a string that way.

Comment: sawa: Yep... you can't store it as a float with a trailing zero. You deal with that when you want to present it to the user - by presenting it as a string with leading and trailing zero. That's the closes you can do to what OP wants.

Comment: Surya - Sorry you felt my explanation was bad. I said it rounds DOWN to the nearest integer. I'm not sure how to make it any clearer?

Comment: You should never use (or recommend) floats for monetary calculations, use [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: @Stefan unless you are calculating tax, exchange rates, interests, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because `0.8.to_i` is `0`.
2. It is impossible.

Comment: but try `"0.8".to_i.round(2)`

Comment: "0.8".to_i.round(2) gives 0.0 for me.

Comment: `"0.8".to_i` returns `0` and `0.round(2)` returns `0.0`